# How to create a complex URL dispatcher

Tags: opa

I'm trying to develop a URL dispatcher to execute a different action depending on the URL. For example:

- http://localhost:8080/   -> go to homepage
- http://localhost:8080/edit?id=2   -> go to edit page
- http://localhost:8080/delete?id=4   -> go to delete page

As for now I got the following code that works:

```
dispatch(uri) =
match uri with
  | {path= [edit] query=[("id", parameter)] ...} -> Customer.edit(parameter)
  | {path= [delete] query=[("sid", parameter)] ...} -> Customer.delete(parameter)
  | {~path ...} -> start()

server = Server.simple_dispatch(dispatch)
```

However in my first attempt I had:

```
  | {path= [edit] query=["id", parameter] ...} -> Customer.edit(parameter)
  | {path= [delete] query=[("id", parameter)] ...} -> Customer.delete(parameter)
```

But the compiler throws an error because of having **"id"** in both lines, apparently the first line is "overriding" the second one. My questions are:

- How to keep the same parameter name **"id"** for both lines without having an error?
- How more than one parameter with different type can be handle? for example localhost:8080/edit?id=2&ask=true&showImage=0
- What is the pattern "..." for?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code you showed really works :). Try for instance:

```
/delete?id="xxx"
/edit?sid="xxx"
```

and you will see that wrong resources are dispatched. The problem is that you put `edit` and `delete` without quotes, so they are treated as *pattern variables* and will match anything (and be bound to the matched value). And that's exactly why your first variant didn't work -- those two patterns are the same up-to variable renaming (edit/delete). What you want (I think) is:

```
dispatch =
| {path = ["edit"] query=[("id", parameter)] ...} -> Customer.edit(parameter)
| {path = ["delete"] query=[("id", parameter)] ...} -> Customer.delete(parameter)
| {~path ...} -> start()
```

#### How to have more than one parameter?

Just extend your pattern matching (first line) to:

```
| {path = ["edit"] query=[("id", id), ("ask", ask), ("showImage", showImage)] ...} -> Customer.edit(id, ask, showImage)
```

But this kind of matching is dangerous as it will *only* work if there are exactly those query parameters and in exactly this order. If you cannot be sure about that better do:

```
| {path = ["edit"] ~query ...} ->
    id = List.assoc("id", query) ? ""
    ask = List.assoc("ask", query) ? ""
   showImage = List.assoc("showImage", query) ? ""
    Customer.edit(id, ask, showImage)
```

now the order does not matter and if the parameter is missing the default value (after `?`) will be used.

#### What is the pattern "..." for?

You are matching against an `uri` variable of type: [`Uri.relative`](http://doc.opalang.org/api/#stdlib.core.web.core.uri.opa.html/!/type_stdlib.core.web.core.Uri.relative), which has more fields than just `path` and `query`. `...` means there may be more fields in the record but we don't care about them (without dots the records would be expected to have only explicitly mentioned fields).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just for information, I promise the code above worked, although I got this warnings when compiling:
>opa customer.opa main.opa

Warning unused
File "main.opa", line 17, characters 10-14, (17:10-17:14 | 802-806)
  Unused variable path.
Warning unused
File "main.opa", line 15, characters 17-23, (15:17-15:23 | 581-587)
  Unused variable delete.
Warning unused
File "main.opa", line 14, characters 17-21, (14:17-14:21 | 471-475)
  Unused variable edit.

Comment: By worked you mean it compiled -- yes, I believe that :). But it would invoke wrong methods for the two URLs that I mentioned.
And I suggest you don't ignore the warnings (or understand them if you do) -- here, they were a clear indication of the problems that you were having.

Comment: I promise, it worked. Now I understand why, for edit actions I had to use "id" as parameter, and for delete "sid" because I didn't specify correctly the matching for the path.

PS:Well just to be sure, I'm currently using my first (not right) solution, and it really works. I can give you the source if you want to test it by yourself :P Anyway, I will adapt the code taking into consideration your answer, thanks!

Comment: To clarify: by it now working I meant that if you open: `/delete?id="xxx"` you will get page for *edit* not for *delete* (because of `id`, not `sid`). Right? :)